# Keras multi label image classification. Do I pass my data correctly? Did I preprocess correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-recognition, multilabel-classification

I am stuck in my keras multilabel problem. I got the hint to work with a custom data generator to create small batches and avoid memory issues.

I work with a csv file with IDs, Filenames and their corresponding labels (21 in total), which looks like this:

```
Filename  label1  label2  label3  label4  ...   ID
abc1.jpg    1       0       0       1     ...  id-1
def2.jpg    1       0       0       1     ...  id-2
ghi3.jpg    1       0       0       1     ...  id-3
...
```

I put the the ids and the labels in dictionaries which has the following output:

```
partition: {'train': ['id-1','id-2','id-3',...], 'validation': ['id-7','id-14','id-21',...]}
labels:    {'id-0': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            'id-1': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            'id-2': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
             ...}
```

As well i have a folder with every image saved as a single npy file, which will be taken by the custom data generator below:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Sequential

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=32, dim=(224,224), n_channels=3,
                 n_classes=21, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            X[i,] = np.load('Folder with npy files/' + ID + '.npy')

            # Store class
            y[i] = self.labels[ID]

        return X, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)
```

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential

# Parameters
params = {'dim': (224, 224),
          'batch_size': 32,
          'n_classes': 21,
          'n_channels': 3,
          'shuffle': True}

# Datasets
partition = partition
labels = labels

# Generators
training_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], labels, **params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(partition['validation'], labels, **params)

# Design model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

...

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(21))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()
```

so far my notebook doesnt give me any Errors, but when i do the following:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train model on dataset
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    epochs=5,
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    workers=2)
```

i get an Error message like this:

Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
...

File "c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

It feels that I pass or use the data somehow incorrect!?
If someone has an idea or a hint how to pass the data in a better manner or tackle this issue, i will appreciate. Even a different approach would be awesome. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`use_multiprocessing=True` is not supported on windows ([github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10842)). remove that and the `workers` parameter.

Comment: thanks, this at least silenced the broken pipe error. now i get a different error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence., i guess there i pass my data incorrectly!?